# Adding mathbb letters to org-entities

Tags: org-mode

To make it so that, i.e., `\vdots` is displayed as ⁞ one can:

```
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
             '("vdots" "\\vdots{}" t "&x2999" "..." "..." "⁞")                
              )
```

However, I get "invalid function" errors when I try to get i.e. `\mathbb{R}` to display as `ℝ`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
             '("vdots" "\\vdots{}" t "&x2999" "..." "..." "⁞")                
             ("mathcal{R}" "\\mathcal{R}" t "&x211D" "R" "R" "R")
              )
```

**Question:** Is there a way to add the mathbb alphabet to `org-entities-user`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the braces in the `name` attribute of the org entity:

```
(setq org-entities-user
      '(("vdots" "\\vdots{}" t "&x2999" "..." "..." "⁞")
        ("mathcalR" "\\mathcal{R}" t "&x211B" "R" "R" "ℛ")
        ("mathbbR" "\\mathbb{R}" t "&x211D" "R" "R" "ℝ")))
```

Comment: Welcome.  Does this also work for the OP's mathcal?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the examples with mathbb to be consistent with the desired symbol ℝ. I have edited the answer to illustrate the use with both symbols \mathbb{R} ℝ and \mathcal{R} ℛ.

Comment: This gets rid of the "invalid function" errors but still doesn't display properly: https://imgur.com/a/ELrKJuA Is this the same on your machine?

Comment: The org entity is `mathcalR`, so you must write `\mathbbR` in org-mode, which is exported in latex as `\mathbb{R}` and displayed as ℝ.